# Locale not changing in signed apk

Tags: android, locale

I have an android app which contains of 4 languages,i.e. English, Hindi, Gujrati and Marathi.
I have 4 strings file in my res folder and when I run the code in debug mode directly to my device it works great. But when i sign the apk and post it on playstore and try to download that it doesn't work.

This is my code for setting the locale :

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String lang = sharedpreferences.getString("lang","en");
        System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! : "+lang);

        Locale locale = new Locale(lang);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
}
```

I extend this BaseActivity to all activities I use.
So I am not able to figure out the issue why it is working fine in debug and not in the signed apk.

Comment: use `getApplicationContext()` instead of `getBaseContext()`

Comment: have a look at this https://proandroiddev.com/change-language-programmatically-at-runtime-on-android-5e6bc15c758

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
 getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
              getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

instead of

```
 getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
            getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

---

Because

> getApplicationContext() - Returns the context for all activities
>   running in application.

and

> getBaseContext() - If you want to access Context from another context
>   within application you can access.